# Android Compose AdapterList update data Asynchronously

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I'm trying to update the AdapterList Composable item asynchronously. I put Image as one of the List Item. The image data is downloading from server using coroutine and update the value using state. When I fling the list items, got following error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asking for measurement result of unmeasured layout modifier
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.getMeasureResult(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:58)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.getMeasuredSize(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:48)
        at androidx.ui.core.Placeable.getWidth(Placeable.kt:40)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNode.getWidth(ComponentNodes.kt:841)
        at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.composeAndMeasureNextItem-BTEqjtU(AdapterList.kt:222)
        at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.consumePendingScroll(AdapterList.kt:151)
        at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState.access$consumePendingScroll$3(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.ui.foundation.ListState$ListMeasureBlocks.measure(AdapterList.kt:277)
        at androidx.ui.core.InnerPlaceable.performMeasure(InnerPlaceable.kt:43)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:99)
        at androidx.ui.core.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:79)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayerWrapper.performMeasure(LayerWrapper.kt:52)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:99)
        at androidx.ui.core.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:79)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:99)
        at androidx.ui.core.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:79)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:99)
        at androidx.ui.core.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:79)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:99)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNode$measure$2.invoke(ComponentNodes.kt:1177)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNode$measure$2.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.ui.core.ModelObserver.observeReads(ModelObserver.kt:151)
        at androidx.ui.core.AndroidComposeView.observeMeasureModelReads(AndroidOwner.kt:487)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNode.measure(ComponentNodes.kt:1176)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this a few times myself with both lists downloading images like you're describing and also lists without any async work being done, but I don't think it's caused by anything we're specifically doing. My impression is that it's just a bug with the current state of Compose.

That being said, [AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:ui/ui-core/src/main/java/androidx/ui/core/AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.kt;l=136?q=Asking%20for%20measurement%20result%20of%20unmeasured%20layout%20modifier) is at least one class that handles this error and references an internal Issue Tracker ticket that's indicating it will be fixed in Android R, at least for that instance.

```
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    // We may get "Asking for measurement result of unmeasured layout modifier" error.
    // TODO(b/153198816): check whether we still get this exception when R is in.
    info.setBoundsInScreen(android.graphics.Rect())
}
```

There's also an upcoming change in `dev11` that updates `AdapterList` [to dispose of compositions scrolled off screen](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1285864/) and I'm curious to see how this affects things.

And if you're just curious about where the error is being thrown you can check out [LayoutNodeWrapper._measureResult](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:ui/ui-core/src/main/java/androidx/ui/core/LayoutNodeWrapper.kt;l=62?q=_measureResult).

Comment: Got this info yesterday. Waiting to check the case in dev11

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154653504

but here is the issue changed to Wont fix

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Compose version 0.1.0-dev14

You can update your compose dependencies to

```
 composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '0.1.0-dev14'
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.3.70-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200424'
}
```